# SSRS: Action "Go to URL" not working after applied to data cell in matrix

Tags: javascript, sql, reporting-services, matrix

I'm having some trouble making a data cell in an SSRS matrix clickable to go to a URL, passing parameters.

I've done this many times before, but something about this expression is keeping the cells from being clickable.

Here's the expression I have under the "Go to URL" action in "Placeholder Properties":

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://Server/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fParent%2fDashboardDetail&Resolved=" + Parameters!Resolved.Value + "&Contact=" + Parameters!Contact.Value + "&Category=" + Fields!Category.Value + "&Range=" + Fields!Range.Value + "', '_blank'))"
```

I've passed through multiple parameters using this same template with no issues.  However, when I run this report, it runs fine, but the cells don't hyperlink.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the toString() method on your parameters to convert them to a string so the + operand can concatenate them together.

So

```
Parameters!Resolved.Value
```

becomes

```
Parameters!Resolved.Value.toString()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The cells are now clickable, which is a huge step in the right direction.  It's successfully passing through the Field values, but not the parameter values.  The parameter values are just passing through a value string "System.Object[]".  Does this have something to do with how I constructed my parameters on the detail report?